# Links underneath fixed position div are clickable on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, positioning, z-index

On our mobile website, I have a footer with fixed positioning and a feed that scrolls underneath it.  The issue that I'm observing is that the links on the feed are clickable from the footer area because these two divs overlap.

Footer:

```
.footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1030;
height:45px;
.background-image-gradient (@topFooterColor, @bottomFooterColor);
box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align:center;
border-top: 1px solid @topFooterBorder;
}
```

The feed is contained in a div called status_updates:

```
.status_updates {
border-left:0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Within the status updates div, there are links to other places on the site (people's profile, status updates, etc.).  The issue that I am observing is that these links remain clickable through the footer (on the bottom 45px of the screen).

I have tried playing with z-index of .status_updates, even setting it to z-index:-1, but this still doesn't work.  My understanding is that z-index of the footer is being ignored because it has fixed positioning.

I know that if I make the .status_updates div absolute with top: 40px (the height of my fixed position header) and bottom:45px (the height of my fixed position footer), and my footer absolute to fall below the .status_udpates div it will fix the issue because the divs no longer overlap.  However, this solution will require me to restructure many other pages on the site.

Is there a solution where I can keep the .footer div with fixed positioning, and the .status_updates div with relative positioning such that the links contained within .status_udpates are not clickable through the footer?

Here is a picture that might help visualize my issue:
[image: Links on the scrollable feed are clickable through the footer]

Comment: Could you show something of your html?

Answer (score 1):

As Torsten mentions above, this is a known browser issue. I had a similar situation and solved it as follows.

If you add a margin-bottom to your scrolling content that is the height of your footer, (eg height of footer is 45px, `margin-bottom: 45px` on scrolling content), then the content would *appear* to scroll behind the footer, but would really just scroll *to* the footer. This way since the link will never be technically *behind* the footer, it'll never have the issue with a click-through.

Of course this only works if your footer isn't transparent/translucent or otherwise designed such that you can "see through" it to the content below.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  But this still doesn't look like it works. Let me explain.  Current the feed (.status_updates) can be very long, suppose 1000px height after rendering. If I add margin to the bottom of status_updates, the content still scrolls underneath the footer. Only at the end of the feed will the links not be behind the footer, but while scrolling, the links are still behind the footer and can be clicked.  (also, no the footer isn't transparent).

Comment: @PaulJavid -- Maybe something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWhFN/2/), then? This is what I was trying to explain, having the content *seem* to scroll behind the footer, but not actually doing so.

Comment: Thanks.  I was aware of this option, which requires me to change the feed to fixed positioning as well.  (as they did with .content in the JSFiddle).  I was trying to see if there was some way around restructuring the content of my site.  If you have any other ideas, I'd love the help!

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Problem with this solution is also that it only works on iOS >5.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. The fixed element can be clicked through if the scroll happened programmatically.

Remy Sharp has a [good article](http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/) about the issue.

Comment: Thanks Torsten.  In my site, there is no programmatic scrolling (e.g. no click event causes the page to scroll)  The user can scroll through the feed manually, but it seems they can still click through the fixed element to links hidden underneath. Any help greatly appreciated!